# Cannot invoke 'getControlPointAtIndex' in Swift project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I've have been attempting to revive a marquee text script that was written in the early days of swift, and make it function in swift 1.2. I have been able to fix all errors except one, which is present in the last portion of the code provided by the original author (who states that he will no longer be updating the project (@ https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel-Swift). The full compiler error is, "Cannot invoke 'getControlPointAtIndex' with an argument list of type '(Uint, values: inout [Float])'.

```
func controlPoints() -> [CGPoint] {
    // Create point array to point to
    var point: [Float] = [0.0, 0.0]
    var pointArray = [CGPoint]()
    for (var i: UInt = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        self.getControlPointAtIndex(i, values: &point)
        pointArray.append(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(point[0]), y: CGFloat(point[1])))
    }

    return pointArray
}
```

The issue occurs on the line 'self.getControlPointAtIndex(i, values: &point), and I have tried everything to fix it. The full file file is provided in the link above.

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple's documentation, the method [`getControlPointAtIndex:values:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CAMediaTimingFunction_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CAMediaTimingFunction/getControlPointAtIndex:values:) expects its arguments to be of type `Int` and `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>`.

So you should change `UInt` to `Int` and allocate a pointer for `point`, something like the following:

```
func controlPoints() -> [CGPoint] {
    // Create point array to point to
    var point = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.alloc(2)
    var pointArray = [CGPoint]()
    for (var i: Int = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        self.getControlPointAtIndex(i, values: point)
        pointArray.append(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(point[0]), y: CGFloat(point[1])))
    }
    point.dealloc(2)

    return pointArray
}
```

Comment: This results in a 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1, address=0x0)'  crash.

Comment: Are you sure this is an issue with the provided code? Perhaps, it's some other part, where the Swift 1.2 changes introduced a `!` where a `?` would have been more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2.1 the following code should work as expected:

```
var controlPoint1: [Float] = [0,0]
function.getControlPointAtIndex(1, values: &controlPoint1)
```